# Every USB flash drive that is plugged in prompts for autoplay twice

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, autoplay

On my Windows 7 laptop, every single USB flash drive causes two prompts from autoplay. Even empty flash drives.

How do I fix this?

Comment: In control panel auto play settings are there multiple entries for removable storage or something similar?

Comment: I'm not sure. Are these the right settings? Here's how they look http://imgur.com/fPh9kwE

Comment: Try changing mixed content to take no action.

Comment: Already tried resetting all defaults and it stays the same. It even happens with empty USB flash drives.

Comment: Does this happen for every USB port?  Front and back?

Comment: Probably should have mentioned it's a laptop. Yes, it happens with both USB 2.0 ports as well as with the USB 3.0 port.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10836/discussion-between-neil-neyman-and-ashitaka)

Comment: Does the drive also show up as a CD drive? It could be a U3 flash drive (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U3), or something similar.

Comment: No, both autoplay prompts looks exactly the same. They feature the usual USB drive icon and present general options such as `Open folder to view files` and `Speed up my system`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be related to power configuration option.Try this and tell, there are some other workaround too

Go into device manager and don't allow the computer to put the device to sleep!

[image]